# Bug in Scanf function

Tags: c

My program is so simple yet it has a bug that I cannot solve.
Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

char name[100];
int age;

printf("What's your name?\n");
scanf("%s", name);

printf("Hey %s!\n",name);

printf("How old are you?\n");
scanf("%d\n", &age);

printf("You're %d years old, cool!\n", age);


return (0);
}
```

I have a bug when I get to the `scanf` for age. Even once I have typed a number e.g 22, I am supposed to press enter. However this just makes a new line. It seems that the program is not able to detect my integer value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
scanf("%d\n", &age);
```

should be

```
scanf("%d", &age);
```

Note that `scanf("%d\n", &age)` is the same as `scanf("%d ", &age)`. This requires the input to be an integer followed by some whitespace (newline for example). The scanning will stop after the next non-whitespace.  It is essentially the same as `scanf("%d %s", ...)` but without storing the string anywhere (I'm doing a bit of hand-waving here).

The manual for `scanf()` may be found here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the \n from your scanf code:

```
printf("How old are you?\n");
scanf("%d", &age);// Used to be  scanf("%d\n", &age);
```

Comment: Also checking the return value for `scanf` would be useful

Comment: Ah right, can you tell me how I can catch the exceptions so they cannot insert a string e.g hello in the place for int? Is there documentation for this? Sorry I'm new to C :)